# Nested vs random effect

Tags: r, random-effects-model, nested-data

I'm having a little trouble analysing a data set from the following experiment: we applied 4 treatments (`control`, `concentration1`, `conc2`, `conc3`) to 5 plants each for a grand total of 20 plants. We repeated the experiment 3 times independently (`bloc`). When I visualised the data, I saw that there was important variability between the bloc on the response variable, so I decided to control the bloc effect as following:

```
mymodel <- aov(y ~ treatment + Error(bloc), data = mydata)
```

But I am not sure it is what I am trying to do. What is the difference between the above and:

```
mymodel <- aov(y ~ treatment + Error(treatment/bloc), data = mydata)
mymodel <- aov(y ~ treatment + treatment/bloc, data = mydata)
```

And which is the most appropriate for my analysis?

I read the "nested effect model" part in the R Book, but it didn't help me. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance

EDIT: We had a total of 60 plants, 20 for each bloc

Comment: Do you have 60 plants all up? Or did 20 plants get 3 repeats of a treatment?

Comment: 60 plants in total (I should have mentionned it), so each bloc had its own 20 plants

Answer (score 1):

This is a balanced randomized block design with replicates. You just need to do

```
mymodel <- aov(y ~ treatment + Block, data=mydata)
```

You could treat the Block as a random effect, but with only 3 blocks, I would leave it as fixed. There is no nesting, because the 60 plants were randomly assigned to their 3 blocks and 4 treatments, without any particular restrictions.